# Custom gem - how to extract?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Ruby/Rails, and I have received a copy of a Rails project.
From what i have read online the gemfile contains the dependencies - i.e other libraries.
So if I have a "gem 'mycustomgem'" in the gemfile, and this gem is not available as open source, is there a way I can extract this gem from the project I have?
I have asked to write a new and alternative version of the rails project, where I am going to be needing this custom gem. Or do I have to contact the guy who wrote the custom gem?

Or have I completely missed something??

Comment: You can reference gems from git repositories, including private git repositories, provided you have SSH keys to access them. http://gembundler.com/git.html

Answer (score 1):

open you Gemfile and replace row

```
gem 'your_gem'
```

with

```
gem 'your_gem', :path => '/absolute_path_to_you_local_folder_with_gem'
```